# Error in OpenCV 2.4.2 "OpenCV Error: Bad flag"

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, computer-vision, homebrew

I just started trying to play with OpenCV and I wrote a small program from a book that is pretty simple. The problem is when I  try to compile it, I get this error. I will give you all the information I have. I installed openCV using homebrew for Mac OS X 10.7.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("usf.gif");
cv::namedWindow("My Image");
cv::imshow("My Image", image);
cv::waitKey(5000);

return 1;
}
```

I compiled liked this:

```
g++ -o test opencvtest.cc -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_ml -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy
```

And this is what I got back when I tried to run it.

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /tmp/homebrew-opencv-2.4.2-oQmu/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
terminate called throwing an exceptionAbort trap: 6
```

Thanks again.

Comment: try loading any other image like jpg or png and check if same error comes.

Comment: That worked perfectly. But I will leave this question up hopefully someone can answer why it doesn't work with gifs. Knowledge is power.

Comment: You can read the docs of `imread` function to know supported formats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because OpenCV doesn't support **gif**:

> The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns it. If the image can not be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL ).Currently, the following file formats are supported:
>
> Windows bitmaps - *.bmp, *.dib (always supported)
>
> JPEG files - *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.jpe (see Note2 )
>
> JPEG 2000 files - *.jp2 (see Note2 )
>
> Portable Network Graphics - *.png (see Note2 )
>
> Portable image format - *.pbm, *.pgm, *.ppm (always supported)
>
> Sun rasters - *.sr, *.ras (always supported)
>
> TIFF files - *.tiff, *.tif (see Note2 )

See [docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imread).

Answer (score 2):

I think the "gifs" are not supported