# OpenCV 2.4.5, eclipse CDT Juno, MinGW error 0xc0000005

Tags: windows, opencv, mingw, eclipse-cdt

On Windows 7 64 bit, AMD processor, I installed OpenCV 2.4.5, with eclipse CDT Juno and MinGW, everything to the latest update. Previously eclipse CDT and MinGW compiled 100+ source files without problems. They even compile this small OpenCV source file,

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    IplImage* img1 = cvLoadImage("lenna.png");
    cvShowImage("MyWindow1", img1);

    cv::Mat img2;
    img2 = cv::imread("lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    cv::namedWindow("MyWindow2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("MyWindow2", img2);

    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

but when I try to Run it then it breaks with notorious

> "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK
>   to close the application."

What might be wrong and what would be solution to this problem?

1. OpenCV (PreCompiled) is unzipped to "C:\OpenCV245PC\ (README,index.rst and CMakeLists.txt are there with all subfolders)
2. Windows System PATH is set to C:\OpenCV245PC\build\x86\mingw\bin
3. Eclipse GCC C++ Compiler, Include paths (-I) is set to "C:\OpenCV245PC\build\include"
4. Eclipse MinGW C++ Linker, Library search path (-L) is set to: "C:\OpenCV245PC\build\x86\mingw\lib"
5. Eclipse MinGW C++ Linker, Libraries (-l) are set to:

> opencv_calib3d245  opencv_contrib245 opencv_core245
>   opencv_features2d245 opencv_flann245 opencv_gpu245 opencv_highgui245
>   opencv_imgproc245 opencv_legacy245 opencv_ml245 opencv_nonfree245
>   opencv_objdetect245 opencv_photo245 opencv_stitching245
>   opencv_video245 opencv_videostab245

Comment: What is your build type, debug or release? Because it seems like you didnt link the debug libraries (245d).

Comment: There are no debug libraries in precompiled version (or at least I can't find them). Anyway, both Release and Debug yields same results - error.

Comment: I had this problem after I installed a bunch of updates to Eclipse 4.23.0. Installing the latest release of Eclipse did not solve the problem. I installed Eclipse 4.24.0 and the problem went away. I have no idea why. Note that I got a Java error code of -1073740771 (0xc000005).

Comment: I had this problem after I installed a bunch of updates to Eclipse 4.23.0. Installing the latest release of Eclipse did not solve the problem. I installed Eclipse 4.24.0 and the problem went away. I have no idea why. Note that I got a Java error code of -1073740771 (0xc000005).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After many trials and errors I decided to follow [this](http://www.argong.com/docs/how-to-OpenCV-2.2.0.pdf) tutorial and to compile my own binaries as it seems that too many people are complaining that precompiled binaries are NOT working for them. Eclipse CDT Juno was already installed.

My procedure was as follows:

1. Download and install MinGW and add to the system PATH with
   c:/mingw/bin
2. Download cmake from http://www.cmake.org and install it
3. Download OpenCV2.4.5 Windows version
4. Install/unzip Opencv to C:\OpenCV245PC\ (README,index.rst and CMakeLists.txt are there with all subfolders)
5. Run CMake GUI tool, then
6. Choose C:\OpenCV245PC\ as source
7. Choose the destination, C:\OpenCV245MinGW\x86  where to build the binaries
8. Press Configure button, choose MinGW Makefiles as the generator. There are some red highlights in the window, choose options as you need.
9. Press the Configure button **again**. Configuring is now done.
10. Press the Generate button.
11. Exit the program when the generating is done.
12. Exit the Cmake program.
13. Run the command line mode (cmd.exe) and go to the destination
     directory C:\OpenCV245MinGW\x86
14. Type "mingw32-make". You will see a progress of building
     binaries. If the command is not found, you must make sure that the
     system PATH is added with c:/mingw/bin. The build continues
     according the chosen options to a completion.
15. In Windows system PATH (My Computer > Right button click >
     Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables > Path) add the
     destination's bin directory, C:\OpenCV245MinGW\x86\bin
16. RESTART COMPUTER
17. Go to the Eclipse CDT IDE, create a C++ program using the sample OpenCV code (You can use code from top of this topic).
18. Go to Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Includes, and add
    the source OpenCV folder "C:\OpenCV245PC\build\include"
19. Go to Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > MinGW C++ Linker > Libraries, and add to the **Libraries (-l)** ONE BY ONE (this could vary from project to project, you can add all of them if you like or some of them just the ones that you need for your project): opencv_calib3d245 opencv_contrib245 opencv_core245 opencv_features2d245 opencv_flann245 opencv_gpu245 opencv_highgui245 opencv_imgproc245 opencv_legacy245 opencv_ml245 opencv_nonfree245 opencv_objdetect245 opencv_photo245 opencv_stitching245 opencv_video245 opencv_videostab245
20. Add the built OpenCV library folder,  "C:\OpenCV245MinGW\x86\lib" to **Library search path (-L)**.

You can use this code to test your setup:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

Mat img = imread("c:/lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("MyWindow", img);

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to put image to the C:/ (or wherever you might find suitable, just be sure that eclipse have read acess.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code,

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

Mat img = imread("lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("MyWindow", img);

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

cause it seems like you are not creating a window for img1, and not assigning imread output to img2.

Comment: Creating a window for img1 is of no importance, actually even creating window for img2 can be omitted (I tested and it works both ways). However, what was important but NOT for error I ask is that I (as you pointed out) haven't assigned imread output to img2. Problem was solved with custom build of binaries for OpenCV2.4.5 using MinGW. Afterwards, there was other error "bad flag error" same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494119/error-in-opencv-2-4-2-opencv-error-bad-flag . Your modification to code resolved that error, thanks for pointing this to me.

Comment: so I changed this line cv::imread("lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); to this img2 = cv::imread("lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);