# OpenCV application crash related to libstdc++-6.dll

Tags: c++, opencv, windows-7, eclipse-cdt, mingw32

I am an opencv, C++, and eclipse CDT starter. I was following a tutorial to learn opencv. However, although I succeeded in compiling my program, it crashed soon after execution. I read through many related Q&A but didn't get a working solution. Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Below is some specification for your reference:

#### System setting

- **OS**: 32-bit Windows 7 Professional (virtual machine)
- **IDE**: CDT 8.2.0 for Eclipse Kepler
- **C/C++ compiler**: mingw32-gcc (4.8.1)
- **OpenCV Package**: opencv2.4.6

#### Detailed procedure

- Downloaded and extracted Eclipse
- Installed MinGW to C:\MinGW. Set "C:\MinGW\bin" to system path [PATH]
- Downloaded and executed OpenCV to C:\opencv. Set "C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin" to system path [PATH]
- Launched Eclipse and in Eclipse:

  - *File>New>C++ Project*: Project name->OpenCVTest, Project Type->Hello World C++ Project, Toolchains->MinGW GCC
  - *Finish*
  - In *Project>Properties>C/C++ Build>Settings>Tool Settings>GCC C++ Compiler>Includes>Include paths (-I)* I added "C:\opencv\build\include".
  - In *Project>Properties>C/C++ Build>Settings>Tool Settings>MinGW C++ Linker>Libraries>Libraries (-l)* I added opencv_core246, opencv_highgui246, and opencv_imgproc246 one after one.
  - In *Project>Properties>C/C++ Build>Settings>Tool Settings>MinGW C++ Linker>Libraries>Libraries search path (-L)* I added "C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib".
- Replaced the OpenCVTest.cpp file content with the following content:

  ```
  #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace cv;
  using namespace std;

  int main( int argc, char** argv )
  {
      if( argc != 2)
      {
       cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
       return -1;
      }

      Mat image;
      image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

      if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
      {
          cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
          return -1;
      }

      namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
      imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

      waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Built the project and got the following console output (assumed successful):

  Info: Internal Builder is used for build
  g++ "-IC:\opencv\build\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\OpenCVTest.o" "..\src\OpenCVTest.cpp"
  g++ "-LC:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib" -o OpenCVTest.exe "src\OpenCVTest.o" -lopencv_core246 -lopencv_highgui246 -lopencv_imgproc246
- Ran the generated .exe without passing a image path (should be working) and the program crashed with the following prompt:

  Problem signature:
    Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
    Application Name: OpenCVTest.exe
    Application Version:  0.0.0.0
    Application Timestamp:    5230da00
    Fault Module Name:    libstdc++-6.dll
    Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
    Fault Module Timestamp:   522c646d
    Exception Code:   c0000005
    Exception Offset: 0001df4b
    OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
    Locale ID:    1033
    Additional Information 1: 4c0d
    Additional Information 2: 4c0d4d78887f76d971d5d00f1f20a433
    Additional Information 3: 4c0d
    Additional Information 4: 4c0d4d78887f76d971d5d00f1f20a433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was not due to the libstdc++-6.dll. The answer of the related thread: [OpenVC 2.4.5, eclipse CDT Juno, MinGW error 0xc0000005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393311/openvc-2-4-5-eclipse-cdt-juno-mingw-error-0xc0000005) actually had solved my problem. I didn't succeed because I left both the pre-built (that came along with opencv download) opencv libraries (*.dll) and the re-built (according to the above solution) libraries exposed under system path. As a result, my program used the pre-built version and ignored the new builds. After I replaced the pre-built *.dll's with the re-built ones, the program ran without any issue.